Unable to use dependency-analysis-gradle-plugin for android to remove unused dependencies
My aim was to remove unused and transitive dependencies
I tried this
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.dependency.analysis) // "1.31.0"
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "com.autonomousapps.dependency-analysis")
}

I'm unable to add
// block getting error as cannot be casted
dependencyAnalysis {
}

//tried with this 

configure<com.autonomousapps.DependencyAnalysisExtension> {
        issues {
            all {
                onUnusedDependencies {
                    severity("fail")
                }
                onUsedTransitiveDependencies {
                    severity("warn")
                }
                onIncorrectConfiguration {
                    severity("fail")
                }
                onUnusedAnnotationProcessors {
                    severity("fail")
                }
                onRedundantPlugins {
                    severity("fail")
                }
                // Ignore ktx dependencies if a transitive dependency is used
                structure { ignoreKtx(true) }
            }
        }
    }

but still it failed so I tried to put inside :app module but still it failed
I tried buildHealth the explodeJar is Failing for all modules without any issues shown.
Was looking for proper use in Kotlin DSL. I tried to follow this https://medium.com/bilue/caring-for-your-dependency-garden-an-approach-to-android-dependency-management-366b484d37b3
Thank you.
